# What can i do to prevent code insertion in Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As far as my Template.JS goes with the power of array and cloning, I fear that a hacker could possibly enter a malicious script into an array and create another clone box with their malicious data entry.  How can i prevent someone from entering malicious data into the Arrays?

Here is my fiddle with the cloning of the boxes as well as array data and 'functionable' buttons.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/NitroXAce/d1qro5g3/14/

If there is a plugin or a script I can enter to prevent malicious data to be in arrays, that would be awesome!  I know there was a thing where you cannot insert code into input.  but I fear the console.log in any browser could interfere maybe...?

Comment: this is front end code? you can't really stop anyone from modifying js in their own browser..

Comment: I don't see any templates or cloning in your fiddle. What are you talking about? And if you're asking whether there's a way to stop someone from tampering with the page within their own browser, no. The best you can do is uglify the code to make it hard to tell what the code does, and make sure you validate on the server-side.

Comment: By "cloning"  I used the length of an array to create boxes or templates to insert images, titles, prices, and button functiins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is coming from your server and is not user input, then the worst a "hacker" can do is pwn their own browser. Not much point to that.

That being said, you shouldn't be using inline event handlers.

Ideally, you should pass off the HTML to the loaded into the DOM (some would argue that constructing it with `createElement` etc. would be better) and attach the event handler to a containing element - ie. using event delegation.

But that's implementation detail. The key answer to your question is that - assuming a trusted source of data (ie. nothing user-generated) - then you don't need to worry about what a "malicious" user might put in. When receiving a form submission, your server should validate whatever is sent to ensure it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, right now I'm learning PHP to create more secure web pages. However the array is only editable on the clients side using a console or similar. So even if someone changed the value, when another client loads the page the values will still be the same. That being said if you're going to be submitting the values to a another page or server you'll have to use a server side language anyway so you can use some form of RegEx in the server side language to prevent any modified inputs.

```
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$client_name)) {

  $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}
```

The above is a small example from my PHP submit form that checks to make sure the value uses only allowed characters and then sets '$error_message' if the name uses invalid characters. Later '$error_message,' which is usually empty, is checked and if it's not empty or null then the script exits and posts the error message to the page.